# add Dictionary items to label?

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to make button to add item to label
this is Dictionary item

```
        var menu = new Dictionary<string, double>();
        //names of the items the user is buying and the count
        var items = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        menu.Add("soda", 0.5);
        menu.Add("water", 0.5);
        menu.Add("juice", 0.5);
        menu.Add("rice", 0.5);
        menu.Add("soup", 0.5);
        menu.Add("chicken", 0.5);
        menu.Add("steak", 0.5);
        menu.Add("beef", 0.5);
```

how make button to add item to label

Comment: what are you writing? WinForms application? Web site? What technologies are you already using?

Comment: Are you trying to add more items to the menu items collection from the button? I think we need a bit more context on what it is you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: private void soda_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (addRemoveMode)
                add_item("Can Soda");
            else
                remove_item("Can Soda");
            update_reciept();
            update_tottal();
        }

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (var m in menu)
{
    label1.Text += m.Key + ":" + m.Value.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
}
```